# Using ajax to fetch products from wordpress database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using WordPress to build a custom products page (page1.php).

I'm using Ajax on the custom products page(page1.php), to call an other page that contains the code below (page2.php), to fetch products from the wordpress database using the code below.

```
<?php  
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'product_cat'    => 'hoodies'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
        echo '<br /><a>' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</a>';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The code above actually works fine when I dont call it through AJAX (i.e. load it directly from www.localhost/wordpress/page2.php), but when I call it through ajax on page1.php, I get the following error;

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class '**WP_Query**' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress-fully-custom\wp-content\themes\storefront\page2.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress-fully-custom\wp-content\themes\storefront\test-page2.php on line 9

how do I fix this please?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you import `WP_Query` in file page2?

Comment: @OPV I dont have the file so I'm not sure how to include it any ideas

Comment: You better try the way wordpress handles ajax request. Using Native wp-ajax.php file.

Comment: Oh, thats even better! Can you please explain how to works or point me to some articles that explain it? thanks alot @Sajjadur Rahman Sagor

Answer (score 3):

Here I have been tried for my theme and it's working nice!

Hope this will work for you.

Scipt code for AJAX CALL:

```
jQuery('#productDataSubmit').click(wc_load_all_products);
    function wc_load_all_orders() {
        jQuery("#wc-products").html("");

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_details.ajax_url,
            data: {action: 'get_wc_products'},
            success: function (data) {
                var products = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                jQuery('#wc-products').html(products.product_html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

actions to call AJAX functions for returning products (add this into functions.php)

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_get_refund_data', 'get_wc_products');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_refund_data','get_wc_products');
```

function for getting products (add this into functions.php)

```
     /**
     * AJAX function for products.
     */
    function get_wc_products() {
    $html="";
    $varition_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'product_cat'    => 'bags'
        );
        $variation_query = new WP_Query($varition_args);
    }


    if ($variation_query->have_posts()) {
            while ($variation_query->have_posts()) {
                 $variation_query->the_post();
                 global $product;
                 $html.= '<tr>';
                 $html.= '<td>'.get_the_ID().'</td>';
                 $html.= '<td>'.get_the_title().'</td>';
                 $html.= '<td>'.$product->get_price_html().'</td>';
                 $html.= '</tr>';
            }
    }

    //Returns records
    $data = [];
    $data['product_html'] = $html;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're viewing the page directly, the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class much be getting imported somehow.  Since this is not happening via AJAX, you may want to include it explicitly on that page.  Could do something like:

```
include_once "path/to/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php";
```

Comment: thanks thats very clever! But its still not working :( Any ideas man?

Answer (score 0):

There Are Tons of tutorials available there about wordpress ajax. You better look at these tuts....

[Wordpress Official Ajax Tutorial](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

[Sitepoint Ajax Tutorial With Some Good Examples](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-a-real-world-example)

[Code Tuts Tutorial For Frontend Ajax](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-primer-on-ajax-in-the-wordpress-frontend-actually-doing-it--wp-27073)

[Smashing Magazine Ajax Tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)

And Now lets give you a quick ajax example here :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".ajax_button_to_click").click(function(event){
    // event.preventDefault(); enable this if you want to stop click 
   behavior
    var ajax_form_input_value = jQuery('#ajax_input_value').val();
    var ajax_text = jQuery('#ajax_text_value').text();
    jQuery.ajax({
       method: "POST", // http request method
       url: ajaxurl, // indicates wp-ajax.php file which will handle the request
       data: {'action':'ajax_function_name', //function name which will handle the ajax request inside your plugin or theme's functions.php file
              'ajax_text_data':ajax_text, //text data to send with the ajax request
              'ajax_form_value: ajax_form_input_value ' }, //form input data to send with the ajax request
       success:function(data) { //on ajax request success run all inside this method
        alert(data); 
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){ //if ajax fails then run this method
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And now the ajax request handling part on the backend.

First Add Js ajaxurl var :

```
add_action('wp_head', 'prefix_ajaxurl');

 function prefix_ajaxurl() {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";
     </script>';
 }
```

Second Add Ajax Action function

```
function ajax_function_name(){ // function name should be same defined in ajax request action var.
     $text = $_POST['ajax_text_data'];
     $input_data = $_POST['ajax_form_value'];
     echo $text;
     echo $input_data;
     die(); //you must write die(); to avoid echoing extra 0;
 } 
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_function_name', 'ajax_function_name' ); ?>
```